# Python changing reference of variable

Tags: python, lambda, properties, reference

I'm trying to create properties at runtime for a class, and i'm currently using this piece of code:

```
class Obj:
  pass

attrs = ["a", "b", "c"]

for attr in attrs:
  attr_print = lambda self: print(attr)
  setattr(Obj, attr, property(attr_print))

o = Obj()
o.a
```

But whatever attribute i'm trying to print, it always prints the last in `attrs`.

It feels like python is changing my previous lambdas at each loop.

Is there a way to prevent this happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use another lambda...

```py
for attr in attrs:
    createProp = lambda a: (lambda self: print(a))
    attr_print = createProp(attr)
    setattr(Obj, attr, property(attr_print))
```

This way, we create a new variable `a` in each loop (this `a` is a parameter/local variable to the function `createProp`), and the `attr_print`s then each refer to their own private `a`s.